# How to add Launch Video for iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add Video(5 seconds) once the app launches.

I have tried to use LaunchStoryboard with AVKitPlayer, but Xcode is not allowing me to assign class for that.

```
class LaunchVideoViewController: UIViewController {

var playerView = AVPlayer()
var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadVideo()
}

private func loadVideo() {


    let pathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/kpsbremen/Documents/KPSE1/KPSE1/launch_video.mov")
    playerView = AVPlayer(URL: pathURL)

    playerViewController.player = playerView


    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }

 }
```

Please guide me.

Comment: You should never do it in the LaunchStoryboard, this is a very short time display, and then the rootViewController will be displayed. After the launch, in the rootViewController present the VideoViewController.

Comment: Means Instead of Launch image you want to show video....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one approach for this issue.
Don't use launch storyboard. Just call first your viewController in which you want to run the video. As Video finishes you can move on next controller.

First -> select main storyboard.

Second -> in AppDelegate Class call the video screen.
Manage the condition for these.

Comment: I tried using Storyboard , but I am getting blank screen.

Comment: print what object containing the data